# Security Trim Web API2 Help Page

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, roleprovider

Is it possible to security trim the Web API 2 Auto-Generated Help page?

I'd prefer not to show clients the details of all of the API - just the parts that are of relevance to them, which will be defined by Roles.